# mongodb not connecting by Robo 3T?

Tags: linux, mongodb, ssh

I can connect mongodb on my virtual machine but when I try to access it on Robo 3T. It is not connecting.

I am using the same user and pass, It is working on ssh or putty but when I try to access db on ide Robo 3T, It is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login to Mongo Shell:

```
mongo
use admin
db.auth("devx","xxxxxx")
show dbs
use db1
> db.getUser("devx")
{
    "_id" : "db1.dbuser",
    "user" : "devx",
    "db" : "db1",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "db1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdmin",
            "db" : "db1"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "db1"
        }
    ]
}
```

It should show something like the above output. If it does not share the output with me.

```
use admin
db.createRole( { role: "executeFunctions", privileges: [ { resource: { anyResource: true }, actions: [ "anyAction" ] } ], roles: [] } )
db.grantRolesToUser("devx", [ { role: "executeFunctions", db: "admin" } ])
db.grantRolesToUser("devx", [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ])
```

[image]

next

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default mongodb v3.6+ listens on local interface only. It means you can ssh to the host and connect to local db only.

To access the db from another machine you can either open an ssh tunnel or configure mongodb to listen on all interfaces, e.g. `mongod --bind_ip_all`.

The later is considered insecure and is not recommended for public IPs.

Robomongo connection interface has a separate ssh tab to configure the tunnel:

[image]

Comment: [root@xxxxx]# mongod --bind_ip_all
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--bind_ip_all'
try 'mongod --help' for more information

Comment: db version v3.2.19

Comment: then it must be a firewall. Anyway ssh tunnel should work.

Comment: [root@moveon-php56 dev]# service firewalld stop
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl stop firewalld.service
[root@moveon-php56 dev]# mongod --bind_ip_all
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--bind_ip_all'
try 'mongod --help' for more information

Comment: `--bind_ip_all` is for v3.6. v3.2 does it by default. Check your config if you explicitly bound it to local interface https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/configuration-options/#net.bindIp and remove that line. Let me stress it again - it is safer to use ssh tunnels.